# Fat Cantor-Lebesgue function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I came across the following theorem the other day,

"If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is monotonic increasing, then $f$ is differentiable a.e."

If the take the standard Cantor-Lebesgue function then I see it is not differentiable on the Cantor set, which is measure zero. Great.

Now construct the analogous function for a fat-Cantor set. It is monotonically increasing, but this time the set of discontinuities (i.e. the fat-Cantor set) has positive measure.

What's going on?

Thanks

Comment: The Cantor-Lebesgue function is continuous on all of $[0,1]$. I think that you are mistaken thinking that it is differentiable at no point of the Cantor set. You are certainly mistaken thinking that the "fat" version is differentiable at no point of your fat Cantor set.

Comment: Are you saying that the function is differentiable everywhere? If so, then it should have derivative zero everywhere, contradicting the mean value theorem.

Comment: I certainly said no such thing. I'm simply saying that it's differentiable at *some* points in your fat Cantor set.